# How to render Google Sign-in Button in Web Component?

Tags: javascript, google-authentication, native-web-component

I wanna to render Google Sign-in Button in these web component's template.
But google client library throws an error when I run the code below

> [GSI_LOGGER]: Unable to resize iframe. No iframe found with id: gsi_189146_2364.

```js
var $gameLoginTemplate = document.createElement("template");
    $gameLoginTemplate.innerHTML = `
        <section>
           <div class="login-button" id="google"></div>
        </section>
    `;
    var $gameLogin = function (e) {
        n(t, e);
        var a = h(t);

        function t() {
            var e;
            return s(this, t), (e = a.call(this)).attachShadow({
                mode: "open"
            }), e
        }
        return o(t, [{
            key: "connectedCallback",
            value: function () {

                this.shadowRoot.appendChild($gameLoginTemplate.content.cloneNode(!0))

                google.accounts.id.initialize({
                    client_id: "",
                    callback(response) {
                        console.debug("[inspect]", { response })
                    }
                });

                google.accounts.id.renderButton(
                    this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".login-button#google"),
                    { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
                );

            }
        }]), t
    }(c(HTMLElement));
    customElements.define("game-login", $gameLogin);
```